# Value of react useState array doesn't update when new value from child component is decremented

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have create a refinement component that sends data to its parent and it works correctly. after data goes to parent component, it will save to an array with useState. array value is ok when data from child component is incremental, but when the value from child component is decremented, the array value is not correct.

Here's the code:

**Refinement.jsx**

```
import { Fragment, useState } from "react";

const Refinement = (props) => {

    let [fileTypeSelected, setFileTypeSelected] = useState([]);

    let changingState = "";

    const CheckBoxHandler = (event, content) => {
        if (event) {
            fileTypeSelected.push(content);
            changingState = "Incremental"
        }
        else {
            fileTypeSelected = fileTypeSelected.filter((c) => c !== content);
            changingState = "Decremental"
        }
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="w-full rounded-md overflow-hidden shadow-sm border">
                <div className="flex justify-between items-center px-4 py-1 bg-biscay-700 text-white border-b">
                    <span className="font-semibold ">{props.RefineName}</span>
                </div>
                {
                    <div className={`px-4 py-2 w-full flex flex-col gap-2 transform transition-all  duration-200 ${props.RefineValue.length <= 5 ? "" : "h-36 overflow-y-scroll scrollbar"} `}>
                        {
                            props.RefineValue.map(m => {
                                return (
                                    <div className="text-sm flex justify-between items-center" key={m.id}>
                                        <span>{m.displayName}</span>
                                        <input className="accent-sky-500 w-4 h-4 rounded-md" onChange={(event) => {

                                            CheckBoxHandler(event.target.checked, m.displayName);

                                            props.onDataModified({
                                                SearchCompnent: props.RefineName,
                                                SearchItem: fileTypeSelected,
                                                SearchState: changingState
                                            });
                                        }} type="checkbox" name="" id="" />
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}
export default Refinement;
```

**App.jsx**

```
import { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import Refinement from "../components/Refinement";

const App = () => {

    const [fileFormatRefine, setfileFormatRefine] = useState([
        { id: 0, displayName: 'PDF' },
        { id: 1, displayName: 'DOCX' },
        { id: 2, displayName: 'PPTX' },
        { id: 3, displayName: 'XLSX' },
        { id: 4, displayName: 'TXT' },
        { id: 5, displayName: 'MP3' },
        { id: 6, displayName: 'MP4' },
        { id: 7, displayName: 'CS' },
    ]);

    const [filterFormatModifiedDate, setFilterFormatModifiedDate] = useState([]);

    let FileFormatQueryTemp = [];

    const FileFormatModifiedEnvent = (enterdModifiedData) => {
        const modifiedData = {
            ...enterdModifiedData
        };

        FileFormatQueryTemp = [];

        for (let index = 0; index < modifiedData.SearchItem.length; index++) {
            FileFormatQueryTemp.push([[modifiedData.SearchCompnent, modifiedData.SearchItem[index]]]);
        }

        setFilterFormatModifiedDate([]);
        console.log(modifiedData.SearchItem.length);
        setFilterFormatModifiedDate(FileFormatQueryTemp);
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <div className="w-full lg:w-5/6 mx-auto flex gap-4 mt-16 px-4">
                <div className="w-1/4 col-start-1 hidden lg:flex">
                    <form className="flex flex-col gap-4 w-full" id="Form" onSubmit={(event) => { event.preventDefault() }}>
                        <Refinement onDataModified={FileFormatModifiedEnvent} MinToShow={3} RefineValue={fileFormatRefine} RefineName="File Format"></Refinement>
                        <button className="h-8 text-white font-semibold text-sm rounded bg-red-600" onClick={() => { console.log(filterFormatModifiedDate.length) }}>Show Array Length</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div className="lg:w-3/4 w-full flex flex-col gap-2">
                    <div className="w-full">
                        <h3 className="text-xs flex items-center font-semibold uppercase mb-2">Filters
                            <span className="h-4 w-4 ml-2 text-xs flex items-center justify-center rounded bg-gray-200 text-black">{filterFormatModifiedDate.length}</span>
                        </h3>
                        
                        <div className="">
                            {
                                filterFormatModifiedDate.map(f => {
                                    return (
                                        <p key={f[0][1]} >{f[0]}</p>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `Decreamental` -> `Decremental`? Shouldn't this variable be in state? Consider using a boolean or symbol rather than a string here.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna change fileTypeSelected state,  you should do next:

```
setFileTypeSelected(prevArray => [...prevArray, content])
```

and in else scope:

```
setFileTypeSelected(prevValue => prevValue.filter((c) => c !== content));
```

You must always change state using his function, which comes inside array as second argument

let's consider this example

const [count,setCount] = useState(0)

setCount is the only function that can change count value

Comment: I tried this way and the problem with decreasing is gone but the only issue is, state value does not change correctly

Comment: You mean at decrementing time ? What is type of "content" or "c" inside filter?